# how to use doveadm -A correctly

Tags: dovecot

I'd like to use doveadm to expunge (and more). When I run

```
 doveadm search -u 'some@email.com' mailbox Trash savedbefore 90d
```

it works. But when I use -A, it doesn't.

```
 doveadm search -A mailbox Trash savedbefore 90d
```

The result is (with debug option)

```
doveadm(root): Error: userdb list: Request timed out
doveadm(root): Debug: expire: Couldn't optimize search query: mailbox Trash not in expire database

doveadm: Error: Failed to iterate through some users
```

my dovecot.conf interesting settings:

```
first_valid_gid = 107
first_valid_uid = 107
last_valid_gid = 107
last_valid_uid = 107
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-master {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
  user = nobody
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_acl
}
protocol lda {
  auth_socket_path = /var/run/dovecot/auth-master
  hostname = brzezina.com.pl
  mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/
  mail_plugins = sieve
  postmaster_address = postmaster@brzezina.com.pl
  sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
}
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins expire
plugin {
  expire = Trash
  expire = Trash/*
  expire = Spam
  expire_dict = proxy::expire
}
```

My userdb is in postgresql, and dovecot-sql.conf.ext has iterate_query uncommented:

```
# Query to get a list of all usernames.
iterate_query = SELECT address AS user FROM users
```

I suppose, that because I run it from root, it tries to find system userdb but it should use sql userdb. But don't know how to force it. I tried to use -S but don't know what.

Comment: This old question does not appear answerable without seeing the `userdb` configuration (which could be queried using the `doveconf` command)